# How to tell when a sentence is using a speech act or habitual action?

Tags: grammar

> 1. I swear, he did that on purpose.
> 2. That was a good movie, I give you that.

In sentences like these, how would you tell if they are talking about habitual action or a speech act? For example, in the first sentence, is the action of swearing done by uttering the sentence or is he just saying that he swears habitually?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act

Comment: The [present simple](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html) is not *only* used to express habitual/repetitive action. *I believe* would be another way of saying "I swear", the speaker (in both examples) is just expressing his opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is hyperbole, just an overemphasis, could be exchanged for "I'm sure he did that on purpose."  It isn't possible for anyone but the doer to be really sure whether the act was done on purpose.

The second sentence sounds to be leading up to a rider being given next. Perhaps, It was a good movie,I'll give you that, but the sound track was terrible.